# Get an hour and minutes of a timestamp in cakePHP/ PHP

Tags: php, string, cakephp, time

Sounds like a silly queston, but I need a quick answer and could not find it.

I have a timestamp: *'15:40:00'*, and I need to create two separate variables: hours and minutes.

Much much appreciated.

Comment: can you paste the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use one function [`sscanf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) <sup>(variables will be `integer` type)</sup> :

```php
sscanf('15:40:00', '%d:%d:%d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/107018)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

[`list()`](http://www.php.net/list) and [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) work well here.

```
list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', '15:40:00');
```